# How can I nest `coalesce(group_concat)` statements?

Tags: mysql, group-concat, coalesce

I am gathering multiple values for `TableA` from two different LookUp Tables, `LUTA` and `LUTB`.

Everything works find when I do

```
Select Name,
coalesce(group_concat(Distinct Type) as TypeA,
coalesce(group_concat(Distinct Type) as TypeB 
from TableA T 
Left Join LUTA A 
on A.RefID=T.ID
Left Join LUTB B
 On B.RefID=T.ID
```

Since I get a result with all records from `TableA` and those that don't have records in `LUTA` or `LUTB` will just have `NULL` values for `TypeA` or `TypeB` as desired.

However I want to return just one `TypeAll` column with `TypeA` and `TypeB` concatenated.

So I tried doing this

```
Select Name,
coalesce(concat(
coalesce(group_concat(Distinct Type),
',',
coalesce(group_concat(Distinct Type)
)) as TypeAll
from
TableA T 
Left Join LUTA A 
on A.RefID=T.ID
Left Join LUTB B
On B.RefID=T.ID
```

Thinking that I'd get `NULL` if both `TypeA` and `TypeB` were empty, concatnenated `TypeA` and `TypeB` when both were populated, and one or the other if one was empty. Yet as I look at it it makes sense the results I got; ``NULL if either `TypeA` or `TypeB` is empty and only a value for `TypeAll` if both `LUTA` and `LUTB` have values.

How can I construct it so I get a value in `TypeAll` as long as at least `LUTA` or ``LUTB is not null?

Comment: can you share tables schema, input data and output data corresponding to provided input?

Comment: `coalesce(group_concat(Distinct Type) as TypeA,` is not valid sql.  please copy and paste your actual working query?  and add sample data and expected results for that sample data; that will enormously clarify what you are asking